# Animating Network Growth with NetworkX and Matplotlib

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, networkx

I would like to animate a graph that grows over time.

This is what I have so far:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ims = []
graph = nx.Graph()
for i in range(50):
    // Code to modify Graph
    nx.draw(graph, pos=nx.get_node_attributes(graph,'Position'))
    im = plt.draw()
    self.ims.append([im])
ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=50, blit=True,repeat_delay=1000)
ani.save('dynamic_images.mp4')
plt.show()
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
 File "main.py", line 204, in <module>
    repeat_delay=1000)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/animation.py", line 356, in __init__
    TimedAnimation.__init__(self, fig, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/animation.py", line 304, in __init__
    Animation.__init__(self, fig, event_source=event_source, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/animation.py", line 53, in __init__
    self._init_draw()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/animation.py", line 363, in _init_draw
    artist.set_visible(False)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_visible'
nicomoto@nicomoto-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/CS8903-SpecialProblem/Code/
```

What I want is an animation, where you can see the graph growing. I can save the graph at each stage, and might be able to create an animation outside matplotlib, but is there any way of getting it work like this?

Comment: What is your backend? I've encountered some animation problems with some backends. Can you run matplotlib's [basic_example.py](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/basic_example.html)?

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly for me.
As for the backend, I am just on ubuntu, python 2.7, numpy, scipy, networkx and matplotlib...all installed within the last few days, so they are the latest version...

Im basically a student, and am trying out a few expereriments, It would be really helpful to animate these graphs, so i can see how they grow!

Comment: I'm not familiar with networkx. Perhaps the issue is that `ArtistAnimation` expects a matplotlib artist and not a nx object?

Comment: Updated my answer, hopefully it's more helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Upon review, that code wasn't nearly as relevant to this problem as I'd thought.  However, I was able to use [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686550/how-to-animate-a-time-ordered-sequence-of-matplotlib-plots) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12822762/pylab-ion-in-python-2-matplotlib-1-1-1-and-updating-of-the-plot-while-the-pro) to cobble together an answer for you.  Here's code that will create a graph, add 50 random nodes and 50 random edges to it, and display an image of the graph after every node and edge is added.  A few of the key changes from your code:

1. This code is based on using `pylab.ion()` (see [here](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Animations) for more info).
2. Your code tries to use one figure and change the image within it.  This code creates a new figure for each frame.
3. This code doesn't write out to .mp4.  If you really need to do that, I would suggest writing the figures out to .png file while rendering them, and converting to mp4 after the fact.
4. Note that this code uses `matplotlib.pyplot.pause()` instead of `time.sleep()`.  The figures won't render if you use `time.sleep()`.

Good luck!

```
import random
import pylab
from matplotlib.pyplot import pause
import networkx as nx
pylab.ion()

graph = nx.Graph()
node_number = 0
graph.add_node(node_number, Position=(random.randrange(0, 100), random.randrange(0, 100)))

def get_fig():
    global node_number
    node_number += 1
    graph.add_node(node_number, Position=(random.randrange(0, 100), random.randrange(0, 100)))
    graph.add_edge(node_number, random.choice(graph.nodes()))
    fig = pylab.figure()
    nx.draw(graph, pos=nx.get_node_attributes(graph,'Position'))
    return fig

num_plots = 50;
pylab.show()

for i in range(num_plots):

    fig = get_fig()
    fig.canvas.draw()
    pylab.draw()
    pause(2)
    pylab.close(fig)
```

Comment: Well sorry for the delay, either way, your suggestion is what got me thinking, here is what I did first, I plotted the graph and stored individual png's and then stiched them together outside...

I also did an implementation with ion, the only problem is I cant save these as gif files, but it is rather cool as you can see changes in run time

Comment: Thanks!  I meant to try an alternative solution using matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation (see http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html for more info), but I just haven't had the time.

Comment: @Skyler This code is quite old and libraries have evolved. A simple workaround is using `random.choice(list(graph.nodes()))` instead of `random.choice(graph.nodes())`. I just added a new answer with how the code could look like nowadays.

Answer (score 17):

An improved version of bretlance's. Hope it will be helpful. It will show **animations** but not **picture after picture**.

Still don't know how the owner of the question 
[Animate drawing networkx edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223191/animate-drawing-networkx-edges) 
made use of matplotlib's animation

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random
import pylab
from matplotlib.pyplot import pause
import networkx as nx
pylab.ion()

graph = nx.Graph()
node_number = 0
graph.add_node(node_number, Position=(random.randrange(0, 100), random.randrange(0, 100)))

def get_fig():
    global node_number
    node_number += 1
    graph.add_node(node_number, Position=(random.randrange(0, 100), random.randrange(0, 100)))
    graph.add_edge(node_number, random.choice(graph.nodes()))
    nx.draw(graph, pos=nx.get_node_attributes(graph,'Position'))

num_plots = 50;
pylab.show()

for i in range(num_plots):

    get_fig()
    pylab.draw()
    pause(2)
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Nice transition between one drawing to another. Decreasing the pause gives a smooth animation. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 6):

As the existing answers are quite old, here is a version of how the code could look like with current versions of matplotlib and networkx.

```py
import random
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

graph = nx.Graph()
num_plots = 50
for node_number in range(num_plots):
    graph.add_node(node_number, Position=(random.randrange(0, 100), random.randrange(0, 100)))
    graph.add_edge(node_number, random.choice(list(graph.nodes())))
    nx.draw(graph, pos=nx.get_node_attributes(graph,'Position'))
    plt.pause(0.5)
```