# Animate a tree (graph kind) in python where nodes change color based on events. Which python packages to use?

Tags: python, animation, user-interface, tree

I am trying to find an easy way to animate at tree where nodes are circles with text in them and edges are lines.

Once in a while an event occurs that changes the status of one of the nodes, and this should change the color of the node.

I have looked at networkx as in [Animating Network Growth with NetworkX and Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437284/animating-network-growth-with-networkx-and-matplotlib) but I am unsure if you can get a correct tree layout here, and that the animation is performant.

I do not have a lot of time so I would greatly appreciate suggestions for easy (hacky) ways of doing this.

The the best thing would be to have a function to call:

change_color(node)

that would update a Qt4 gui or something similar. It would be really good if I can use a graph/tree library so that I only have to specify the tree in a simple format and the library takes care of positioning nodes in the gui.

Comment: Did you try the code at the link you suggested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437284/animating-network-growth-with-networkx-and-matplotlib?  Does it do what you need?

Comment: @Aric I ended up rolling my own with pyQt4. Just what I was hopping to avoid. I tried the code, but decided it would take to long to understand those libraries to do what I wanted