# make matplotlib imshow blocking print() in a for loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

In ipython notebook, I am using matplotlib.pyplot imshow in a for loop like this:

```
for i in range(3):
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(I[i])
    print("some explanation for image " + str(i))
```

Basically I hope to show each image followed by a print out sentence. But what I get is 3 sentences are printed out together, then followed with 3 images.

I tried to use time.sleep(1) before print() but does not work. Any idea to get the outputs of plt.imshow() and print() interleaving with each other?

Comment: This thread may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686550/how-to-animate-a-time-ordered-sequence-of-matplotlib-plots

Answer (score 1):

Not what you asked for, but it will serve the same purpose:

```
for i in range(3):
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(I[i])
    plt.title("some explanation for image " + str(i))
```

[image: Jupyter notebook showing images with titles]

Comment: Thanks. I worked around with something similar to your code: use ax.annotation() to add text annotation aside.